# Sun as a light source using opengl and c++

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I am working on the solar system and I am trying to get the sun to be the central light source of this program but it's not working the way I thought it would.

Here is a picture of what I have without lighting.
[image]

Here is the same program with lighting.

[image]

A different angle here so you can see that the Earth has no shadow as it is supposed to (ignore the red on the moon, that's for my reference)

[image]

I don't know if you can tell, but it looks like the light is centered in each sphere, and not in the Sun.
The shadow on the Earth is as if the light was coming from the top. Same with the Sun. The Sun here is not a light source, it's just a sphere that is also being lit by some some source. There is no shadow from the Earth on the moon or from the moon on the Earth.

This here is the code that draws the system

```
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat pos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
//SUN
        //Picture location, major radius, minor radius, major orbit, minor orbit, angle
Planet Sun ("/home/rodrtu/Desktop/SolarSystem/images/Sun.png", 
             100, 99, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0);
double sunOrbS = 0;
double sunRotS = rotatSpeed/10;
//orbit speed, rotation speed, moon reference coordinates (Parent planet's major and minor Axis)
Sun.displayPlanet(sunOrbS, sunRotS, 0.0, 0.0);

//EARTH
Planet Earth ("/home/rodrtu/Desktop/SolarSystem/images/EarthTopography.png", 
           50, 49, 500.0, 450.0, 23.5);
double eaOrbS = orbitSpeed*2;
double eaRotS = rotatSpeed*5;

Earth.displayPlanet(eaOrbS, eaRotS, 0.0, 0.0);
//Orbit path
drawCircle(800, 720, 1, 50);

//EARTH'S MOON
Planet Moon ("/home/rodrtu/Desktop/SolarSystem/images/moonTest.png", 
           25, 23, 100.0, 100.0, 15);
double moOrbS = rotatSpeed*4;
double moRotS = eaOrbS;

Moon.displayPlanet(moOrbS, moRotS, Earth.getMajorAxis(), Earth.getMinorAxis());

orbitSpeed+=.9;
if (orbitSpeed > 359.0)
 orbitSpeed = 0.0;

rotatSpeed+=2.0;
if (rotatSpeed > 719.0)
 rotatSpeed = 0.0;
```

These next two functions are responsible for coordinates and drawing the spheres

```
void Planet::setOrbit(double orbitSpeed, double rotationSpeed, 
              double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY) 
{
    majorAxis = orbitSemiMajor * cos(orbitSpeed / 180.0 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);
    minorAxis = orbitSemiMinor * sin(orbitSpeed / 180.0 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);

    glTranslate(majorAxis+moonOrbitX, minorAxis+moonOrbitY, 0.0);
    glRotatef(orbitAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glRotatef(rotationSpeed, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

}

void Planet::displayPlanet(double orbitSpeed,double rotationSpeed, 
               double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY)
{
    GLuint surf;
    Images::RGBImage surfaceImage;
    surfaceImage=Images::readImageFile(texture);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(0, &surf);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, surf);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    surfaceImage.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB);

    glPushMatrix();
    setOrbit(orbitSpeed,rotationSpeed, moonOrbitX, moonOrbitY);
    drawSolidPlanet(equatRadius, polarRadius, 1, 40, 40); 
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

If I'm way off on what I am doing could you point me to a good tutorial? I have read a few but I guess I didn't understand them as I thought I did.
If I'm on track, could you show me where I'm wrong and what I need to do right?

Comment: This looks fine to me, what exactly are you trying to achieve? I may not have understood correctly.

Comment: I'll put another picture here... The Earth's light is not coming from the Sun.

Comment: Oh, you mean a shadow from the moon on the Earth. It was hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: the shadow on the Earth is as if the light was coming from the top. Same with the Sun. The Sun here is not a light source, it's just a sphere that is also being lit by some some source. There is no shadow from the Earth on the moon or from the moon on the Earth.

Comment: You need to set the position of the light source, check my answer for how to do that. It's placing the light at the default position I believe so it's illuminating everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);` and set the position of the light source to the center of the sun.

Comment: what kind of variable is `pos`? I keep getting an error when I do this. 
Error below:

In member function ‘virtual void SolarSystem::display(GLContextData&) const’:
solarSystem.cpp:31:40: error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘const GLfloat* {aka const float*}’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘void glLightfv(GLenum, GLenum, const GLfloat*)’
make: *** [o/g++-3.g0.O3/solarSystem.o] Error 1

Comment: The W component of the position is also important to mention though. If the w component of the position is 0, the light is treated as a directional source.

Comment: I thought that that's what I was doing with `GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };`

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues That just sets the RGBA values for the diffuse light, you need to set the position of the light.

Comment: This helped, but I get no shadow from the moon on the earth or from the earth on the moon. Can I add a new picture and modify my question here or should I add a new question? I haven't been using stackoverflow for very long

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues as grimmy said did u set the correct W component on the light?

Comment: I'm reading up on it because I don't really understand what this W component is.

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues Yeah reading up on this is the best thing to do. Learn some more in the process. If you still have troubles you can post a new question since this one already has quite a bit of content.

Comment: The w component is the 4th value of a 4 dim vector. X, Y, Z, W. You'll get to know this friend a lot more as you keep learning :)